# OPLON LBL ADC: is it possible to use a single VIRTUAL DOMAIN to manage all the incoming requests for all the subdomains?

Tags: http, proxy

I need to use just a single virtual domain to accept all the request for the related subdomains.

*E.g.,
*.mydomain.com should be able to accept this.mydomain.com that.mydomain.com another.mydomain.com and so son....*

Moreover the proxied request should not alter the HOST field in the HTTP request since the endpoints use a "virtual domain" like engine to mux/demux the requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course, in the OPLON LBL ADC the domain name is actually a regular expression.

For example, if you set different endpoints (backend servers) associated with the following regexs as domain names:

Domain= ^[a-m].*.*myoplon.net|^[a-m].*.lbl.com

        endpoint SERVER001 port 8080

        endpoint SERVER002 port 8080



Domain= ^[n-z].*.*myoplon.net|^[n-z].*.lbl.com

        endpoint SERVER003 port 8181

        endpoint SERVER004 port 8181

Depending on the domain name requested by the client if starts from "a" to "m" or "n" to "z", LBL ADC will balance the requests on SERVER001-SERVER002 or SERVER003-SERVER004.

NOTE: Before using the regular expression, you can use the Regexp helper tool in the HTML5 LBL administrator console